# Is it possible to find a coordinate chart associated to a change of basis in the tangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am following Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, but this question is motivated from studying bases of vectors in the context of general relativity. Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold. In the standard construction of a basis of a tangent space, we choose a chart $(U,\varphi)$ whose coordinate domain contains $p\in M$, and the pre-image $(d\varphi_p)^{-1}(\frac{d}{dx^i})\rvert_{\varphi(p)}$ provides a basis on the tangent space $T_pM$ since there is an isomorphism between $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_pM$.

Since $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ is (isomorphic to) a vector space, I am allowed to choose a different basis for this space. As an explicit example, for $n=3$ in spherical coordinates, the coordinate basis is $\{\partial_r,\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi\}$. But I may wish to redefine my basis to be $\{\partial_r,\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta,\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\partial_\phi\}$ for every tangent space (Motivation: if I assume the Euclidean metric, this gives me a normalised basis). My question is whether I can find a coordinate map $\psi$ whose coordinate basis is this.

I think my confusion is arising because I haven't actually changed the coordinates used to describe the coordinate domain $U$, but I have changed the basis of the tangent space. The preimage of these new bases are still a basis for $T_pM$ because $d\varphi_p$ is linear. But can my choice of basis at the tangent space induce a new coordinate system?

Comment: In general no.  The frame $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is integrable (i.e., there exists coordinate neighbourhood $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ such that $X_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$) if and only if $[X_i,X_j]=0$ for all $i,j$.  The proof is to let coordinates $x^i$ be given by composing flowing $X_i$ for time $x^i$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$, and conversely $[\partial_i,\partial_j]=0$ gives $[X_i,X_j]=0$.

Comment: For details, see Theorem 9.46 (Canonical Form for Commuting Vector Fields) in Lee's book.